# Is there a Share menu in Linux desktop environments?

Tags: gnome, desktop-environment, desktop, file-sharing, menu

1. Does any DE have a 'Share menu' which allows sending files to and via installed applications like email clients, messengers, etc. (similar to MacOS and Android)?
2. And in particular, is it possible to add such a functionality to Gnome 3?

[image]